# How to make settings in FIBPlus Tools Preferences?

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe4, firebird2.5, fibplus

I am using FIBPLUS 7.5 with Delphi XE4. I want to make some changes in the settings of FIBPLUS Preferences. I am following this article of Devrace:

http://www.devrace.com/en/fibplus/articles/4763.php

But I am unable to find and open the screen whose screenshot is mentioned in the article. From where can I access this FIBPlus Preferences screen?

Comment: The article describes a tool called FIBPlusTools that you need to buy.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - But when I click on Download, it takes me to the page http://www.devrace.com/en/fibplus/download/ where is the link of downloading FIBPLUS 7.5 which I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the **Designtime packages for FIB-Tools**, there is a install instruction in your FIB-Folder.

Comment: I can't find any Designtime packages for FIB-Tools in Devrace folder where it is installed.

Comment: @nkp FIBPlus_Editors_XE4.bpl should be in your FIB Sources folder

Comment: It is already installed and in Tool Palette, I can only find FIBPlus and FIBPlusService. There is no any component under these tabs where FIBPlus Preferences can be set.

Comment: @nkp There should be a menu entry in the Main menu of the IDE. Maybe you must reinstall FIB for XE4. If these doesn't help create a support tickte on Devrace

Comment: @Firtzw - okay, I got that screen. Thanks. But StartTransaction was already checked in there. It did not solve my problem :(